How to Codec Case Class using Vulcan in FS2 Kafka
I have the following case classes. Trying to produce a avro message to Kafka, using FS2 and Vulcan to do the Codec.
case class People(name: String, address: Seq[Address])

case class Address(`type`: AddType.Value, street: String, suburb: String)

object AddType extends Enumeration {
  type AddType = Value
  val H, P = Value
}

case class PeopleKey(eid: String)

I created the following Codec:
object codecPeople {

  implicit val keyEncoder: Codec[PeopleKey] = Codec.derive[PeopleKey]
  implicit val valueEncoder: Codec[People] = Codec.derive[People]

  implicit val seqAddressAvroCodec = Codec.seq[Address]
  implicit val addressAvroCodec: Codec[Address] = Codec.derive[Address]

  implicit val AddressTypeCodec: Aux[EnumSymbol, AddType] = Codec.enumeration[AddType](
    name = "AddressTypeAvro",
    namespace = "au.com.avro",
    symbols = List("H", "P"),
    encode = {
      case AddType.H => "H"
      case AddType.P => "P"
    },
    decode = {
      case "H" => Right(AddType.H)
      case "P" => Right(AddType.P)
      case e => Left(AvroError(s"$e is not a AddressTypeAvro"))
    },
    default = Some(AddType.H)
  )
}

To Codec the Seq[AddressAvro], I am writing this:
implicit val seqAddressAvroCodec = Codec.seq[AddressAvro]
Looks like it does not work. Can anyone help?
======================================================
Add more details:
It throws runtime error, and points to the Codec code
implicit val peopleEncoder: Codec[People] = Codec.derive[People]
[info]   Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException:
[info]   at vulcan.Codec$.collection(Codec.scala:759)
[info]   at vulcan.Codec$.list(Codec.scala:796)
[info]   at vulcan.Codec$.seq(Codec.scala:1128)
***[info]   at au.com.stackoverflow.codecPeople$.<clinit>(codecPeople.scala:23)***
[info]   at au.com.stackoverflow.producePeopleTest.produceCamCustData(producePeopleTest.scala:27)
[info]   at au.com.stackoverflow.producePeopleTest.$anonfun$new$2(producePeopleTest.scala:18)
[info]   at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)


The following is the code to produce kafka message:
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.kafka._
import fs2.kafka.vulcan.{AvroSettings, SchemaRegistryClientSettings, avroSerializer}
import fs2.{Chunk, Pipe, Pure, Stream}
import org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

class producePeopleTest extends AnyFreeSpec {

  "Integration test" - {
    "should be able to produce kafka records" in {
      val config = TestAppConfig("localhost:9092", "http://localhost:8081")
      produceCamCustData(config).compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()

    }
  }

  private def produceCamCustData(config: TestAppConfig): Stream[IO, ProducerResult[PeopleKey, People]] = {
    val tmsData: ProducerRecords[PeopleKey, People] = generateRecords()
    val avroSettings: AvroSettings[IO] = AvroSettings(SchemaRegistryClientSettings[IO](config.kafkaSchemaUrl))

    implicit val keySerds   = avroSerializer[PeopleKey].forKey(avroSettings)
    implicit val valueSerds = avroSerializer[People].forValue(avroSettings)

    val producerSettings =
      ProducerSettings[IO, PeopleKey, People].withBootstrapServers(config.kafkaBrokers)
    val producer
      : Pipe[IO, ProducerRecords[PeopleKey, People], ProducerResult[PeopleKey, People]] =
      KafkaProducer.pipe(producerSettings)

    val fs2Data: Stream[Pure, ProducerRecords[PeopleKey, People]] = fs2.Stream(tmsData)
    val res: Stream[IO, ProducerResult[PeopleKey, People]]        = fs2Data.through(producer)

    producerHandleErrorRec(res)
  }

  private def producerHandleErrorRec[A](stream: Stream[IO, A]): Stream[IO, A] =
    stream.handleErrorWith(_ =>
      Stream.sleep[IO](10.seconds) >> Stream.eval(IO.println("Produce Fail")) >> producerHandleErrorRec(stream))

  private def generateRecords(): ProducerRecords[PeopleKey, People] = {
    val key = PeopleKey("1102388657")
    val address = Address(
      `type` = AddType.H,
      street = "1 Anna St",
      suburb = "Melbourne"
    )
    val value = People(
      name = "Su",
      address = Seq(address)
    )

    ProducerRecords(
      Chunk.from(
        List.fill(1)(
          ProducerRecord("test.people.topic.avro", key, value)))
    )
  }

}

=== Answer from Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez ===
Reorder the Codec as "Objects are initialized from top to bottom". It works on my mac, messages are successfully produced.
object codecPeople {

  implicit val AddressTypeCodec: Aux[EnumSymbol, AddType] = Codec.enumeration[AddType](
    name = "AddressTypeAvro",
    namespace = "au.com.avro",
    symbols = List("H", "P"),
    encode = {
      case AddType.H => "H"
      case AddType.P => "P"
    },
    decode = {
      case "H" => Right(AddType.H)
      case "P" => Right(AddType.P)
      case e => Left(AvroError(s"$e is not a AddressTypeAvro"))
    },
    default = Some(AddType.H)
  )

  //  implicit val seqAddressAvroCodec = Codec.seq[Address]
  implicit val addressAvroCodec: Codec[Address] = Codec.derive[Address]

  implicit val keyEncoder: Codec[PeopleKey] = Codec.derive[PeopleKey]
  implicit val valueEncoder: Codec[People] = Codec.derive[People]

}


I am new to this Vulcan and FS2 thing, please help.

What does "doesn't work" mean here? A compile error? If so show it. A Runtime Exception? If so show it. Some unexpected behavior? If so, write a test that fails and show it.

Thanks for your comment, have added more details.

objects are initialized from top to bottom. The Codec.derive[People] process needs the addressAvroCodec but this one has not been initialized yet, making it a null. - The fix is just to properly order the declarations in the use order.

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It works, THANKS. Will update my post with your answers.
